# Count appearances of value in second column based on unique value in first column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

The easiest way to explain this is given this table in Oracle SQL...

```
+-----------------+------------+
| COUNTRY         | VALUE      |  
+-----------------+------------+
| England         | A          |
| England         | A          |
| England         | A          |
| England         | B          |
| England         | B          |
| France          | A          |
| France          | A          |
| France          | B          |
+-----------------+------------+
```

how would I produce this result, which is the count of A's and B's for the unique values in column COUNTRY

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| COUNTRY   | COUNT(A)   | COUNT(B)   |   
+-----------+------------+------------+
| England   | 3          | 2          |
| France    | 2          | 1          |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I'm sure this has already been answered, I just don't know how to ask the question.
Thanks

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Wait, what's the expected result if someone later inserts "England, C"?

Comment: I want to count only occurrences of 'A' and 'B'.  'C' would count towards neither.

Comment: Then do as I first suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
select country,
       sum( case when value = 'A' then 1 else 0 end ) numA,
       sum( case when value = 'B' then 1 else 0 end ) numB
  from table
 group by country
```

is one example of conditional aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( COUNTRY, VALUE ) AS
SELECT 'England', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'England', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'England', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'England', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'England', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'France',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'France',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'France',  'B' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR value IN ( 'A' AS "COUNT(A)", 'B' AS "COUNT(B)" ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> COUNTRY | COUNT(A) | COUNT(B)
> :------ | -------: | -------:
> England |        3 |        2
> France  |        2 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9da69b0ad66f1e498779531684f09313)*